# get _id of existing document from MongoDB after updateOne() found a match? Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am running an updateOne() to find a user by their email address.  If the user doesn't exist, I create one using "upsert:true"  I am able to run the search on MongoDB and if the user doesn't exist it creates the user, else it returns that the user exists already.

When the user doesn't exist the response gives me the _id of the new field at "upsertedId:" and I can therefore use that _id to use on the front end of my application.  However, if the document alrady exists, I can't seem to find where in the response the _id is shown.  So when the document already exists in the database the "upsertedId" is "null" which I understand because nothing was created.

How can I get the _id of the field that was found to exist already?

Below is my code:

```
const userInfoInMongo = async (userContactEmail, userName) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    userEmail = { userEmail: userContactEmail };
    dataToUpdate = { userEmail: userContactEmail, userName: userName };

    db.collection("users").updateOne(
      userEmail,
      {
        $set: dataToUpdate,
      },
      { upsert: true },

      (e, res) => {
        if (e) {
          console.log(e);
        } else {
          console.log(res);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
```

Comment: You can use the [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate) method which returns the document with its fields.

Comment: Prasad_ that worked perfectly.  I changed updateOne to findOneAndUpdate and left the rest of the code alone and it returned what I needed.  Thank you very much.